# RxJava allow multiple onError calls

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm attempting to allow for an infinite stream of both on next and on error calls.

The below code uses the [`retry()`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/trm2n6S4FSc) method which I assumed would allow me to see all 3 calls to `onNext` however after the error nothing else is called.

```
public class TesterClass {
​
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final PublishSubject<Void> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
​
        publishSubject
                .retry()
                .subscribe(
                        aVoid -> System.out.println("onNext"),
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> System.out.println("onComplete")
                );
​
        publishSubject.onNext(null);
        publishSubject.onNext(null);
        publishSubject.onError(new Exception("onError"));
        publishSubject.onNext(null);
    }
}
```

My ideal use case would allow me to subscribe and take action on all errors and all next calls from the subject / observable.

I've also attempted to implement a solution using a custom `Operator` as shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/trm2n6S4FSc) but I've had no luck with this either.

Is it a possibility to achieve what I'm setting out to do or does the design of RxJava's onError breaking the chain completely block this idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in this thread ([Rxjava discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2858)) this can't be done.

Wrap the error into a message through OnNext if the error should not terminate the stream.